# Проблема считывания данных из файла java

Tags: java, файлы

У меня есть класс Person, в котором созданы геттеры и сеттеры, а также переменные name (String), age(int), height(double), width(double). Я хочу считать информацию из файла и присвоить этим переменным соответствующие данные о человеке.

- setName принимает значение String
- setAge принимает значение int
- setHeight и setWidth принимают значения double

Вроде звучит все просто, но программа выдает ошибку **Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ObjectOriented {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Scanner inputFile=new Scanner(new File("src\\statistics.txt"));

        Person dima=new Person();
        dima.setName(inputFile.nextLine());
        dima.setAge(inputFile.nextInt());
        dima.setHeight(inputFile.nextDouble());
        dima.setWidth(inputFile.nextDouble());
        dima.userInformation();
   }
}
```

> userInformation() выводит информацию о пользователе.

Сам вайл выглядит так:

```
Dima
20
172.5
61.9
```

Comment: Точка в текстовом файле, замените её на запятую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените точку в текстовом файле, или если это невозможно, используйте парсинг. Прошу заметить так же, что после метода nextInt нужно вызывать nextLine.

```
    Person dima = new Person();
    dima.setName(inputFile.nextLine());
    dima.setAge(inputFile.nextInt());
    inputFile.nextLine();

    dima.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(inputFile.nextLine()));
    dima.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(inputFile.nextLine()));
    //dima.setHeight(inputFile.nextDouble());
    //dima.setWidth(inputFile.nextDouble());
    dima.userInformation();

   //И закрывать не забываем 

   inputFile.close();
```

В принципе такой подход мне кажется даже лучше, потому что внутри у nextDouble всё тот же

```
 try {
            return Double.parseDouble(processFloatToken(next(floatPattern())));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            position = matcher.start(); // don't skip bad token
            throw new InputMismatchException(nfe.getMessage());
        }
```